# remove duplicates from json array and combine its id's using node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

In the following code newData print as follows

```
var newData =(JSON.parse(jobData));
console.log(newData);
```

currently it contains 5 values.it may varying

```
[{
    mode: daily,
    id: '71'
    os: 'Win37'
}, {
    mode: daily,
    id: '45'
    os: 'Win37-1'
}, {
    mode: daily,
    id: '37'
    os: 'Win64'
}, {
    mode: daily,
    id: '86'
    os: 'Win37'
},{
    mode: daily,
    id: '7'
    os: 'Win64' ];
```

from the above json array i have to create array like this how it is possible?
ie create same `os` `'Win37'` with different `id`.If duplicate `os` present combine its `ids` as follows

```
MynewArray = [{
    mode: daily,
    id: '71,86'
    os: 'Win37'
 }, {
    mode: daily,
    id: '45'
    os: 'Win37-1'
 }, {
    mode: daily,
    id: '37,7'
    os: 'Win64'
 }];
```

Comment: i dont know how to create this..:-(\

Comment: You can't create anything like this: {`id: '71','86'`}, it's just a syntax error.

Comment: then how like `id :'71,86'`??is it possible?

Comment: Yes, that is possible, or maybe `{id: ['71','86']}`.

Comment: yea like `id :'71,86'`

Comment: please help.if you have any ideas?i edited my question as `id :'71,86'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are syntax errors in your code, missing `,` and quotes for `mode` values, after fixing the errors, you can try the following, `neu` array's `id` properties are arrays and `o` here refers to the original array.

```
var neu = [], l = o.length;

for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    var f = neu.filter(function(e, _) {
       return e.os === o[i].os;
    });   
    if (f.length) {
        f[0].id.push(o[i].id);
    } else {
        neu.push({
            os: o[i].os,
            id: [o[i].id],
            mode: o[i].mode
        });
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLpZe/)

Comment: one doubt also what is this underscore ` var f = neu.filter(function(e, _) {`

Comment: @Sush That's the index, `_` is a valid variable name.