# Filter values from a json data using node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Here is the json data

```
var myArray = [{  
        id: '71',   
        os: 'VM-WIN7-64'
    }, {    
        id: '45',
        mode: 'weekly',
        os: 'VM-WIN7-32'
    }, { 
        id: '37',   
        os: 'VM-WIN7-64',
    }, { 
        id: '67',
        mode: 'daily',
        os: 'VM-WIN7-32-1',
    }];
```

From this how can i filter only `mode:daily`, `mode:weekly` as below.I have to remove other values except ``` mode:daily``mode:weekly ```

```
var myArray = [{    
        id: '45',
        mode: 'weekly',
        os: 'VM-WIN7-32'
    }, { 
        id: '67',
        mode: 'daily',
        os: 'VM-WIN7-32-1',
    }];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove duplicates from json array and combine its id's using node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964543/remove-duplicates-from-json-array-and-combine-its-ids-using-node-js)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
myArray = myArray.filter(function(o){
    return (o.mode === 'weekly' || o.mode === 'daily');
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cZXdX/)**